# Problem during upgrade to 18.04 - could not escape from suggested file comparison

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

### **[edit] You can ignore this request, I could not find a clear path forward so backed up my home folder and forced a reboot.  (It didn't want to reboot with dpkg lock in place).  I managed to log back in to the system but it wasn't right and decided to re install.**

I recently upgraded my laptop to 17.10 and today decided to continue on to 18.04 and ran do-release-upgrade again.

During the upgrade I was asked if I wanted to keep the existing 'resolved.conf' file or accept the updated version.    I decided to examine the differences and was presented with the usual "+-" comparison lines however I was unable to return to the upgrade script.  If memory serves there was always an option at this point to revert to the script but I could not see one - I tried "enter", "esc" (as I write this I realise maybe I should have and didn't try "q") but was still stuck in the comparison view and eventually I hit "Cntrl-C".

That threw me back out to the command line and out of the upgrade script.

I doubted the script had finished what it was doing so to check I tried to install something and got...

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Looking at the log - it appears to have installed a lot and these are the last lines...

```
2018-08-01 01:32:36 status half-installed libpam-runtime:all 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu3.1
2018-08-01 01:32:36 status half-installed libpam-runtime:all 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu3.1
2018-08-01 01:32:36 status unpacked libpam-runtime:all 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
2018-08-01 01:32:36 status unpacked libpam-runtime:all 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
2018-08-01 01:32:37 startup packages configure
2018-08-01 01:32:37 configure libpam-runtime:all 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2 <none>
2018-08-01 01:32:37 status unpacked libpam-runtime:all 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
2018-08-01 01:32:37 status unpacked libpam-runtime:all 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
2018-08-01 01:32:37 status unpacked libpam-runtime:all 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
2018-08-01 01:32:37 status half-configured libpam-runtime:all 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
2018-08-01 01:32:37 status installed libpam-runtime:all 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
2018-08-01 01:32:37 configure libapparmor1:amd64 2.12-4ubuntu5 <none>
2018-08-01 01:32:37 status unpacked libapparmor1:amd64 2.12-4ubuntu5
2018-08-01 01:32:37 status half-configured libapparmor1:amd64 2.12-4ubuntu5
2018-08-01 01:32:37 status installed libapparmor1:amd64 2.12-4ubuntu5
2018-08-01 01:32:37 configure systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.3 <none>
2018-08-01 01:32:37 status unpacked systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.3
2018-08-01 01:32:37 status unpacked systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.3
2018-08-01 01:32:38 status unpacked systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.3
2018-08-01 01:32:38 status unpacked systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.3
2018-08-01 01:32:38 status unpacked systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.3
2018-08-01 01:32:38 status unpacked systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.3
```

I also did a count for the number of packages unpacked verses installed...

```
$ cat /var/log/dpkg.log|grep unpacked -c
1114

$ cat /var/log/dpkg.log|grep installed -c
749
```

So I think this confirms it has not finished correctly so am posting here for help (system is currently working and I don't want to rebootit just yet, just in case ).

Given that I exited/stopped it a prompt for input...
- is it possible to restart the upgrade from where it left off?
- or is there a better course of action?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process